# Does Einstein Lead Scoring work with formula fields?

Tags: leads, einstein

Aloha Stack Exchange,

I was just wondering, whether Salesforce Einstein Lead Scoring also works with formula fields?
Do you have any experience with this or any refernce to offical Salesforce documentation?

We do have a custom object related to our leads and want to use information from that custom object on the lead for Einstein Lead Scoring.

Now we do wonder, whether to reference the fields via formula fields on the lead or to better post the values there via flow.

What do you think? :)

Thanks a lot & Best regards.